# OpenCV: How to get corners of CvBox2D?

Tags: opencv, xna, emgucv

I need to find corner positions of `CvBox2D` (or `MCvBox2D`) to map found contours on game object in XNA. I have a problem with correct translation of rotation angle. I thought that this is kind of basic operation but I kind find any  solution in Internet.

I tried:

```
rotationAngle = box.angle * (180.0/ CV_PI);
angle = box.angle;
box.angle=rotationAngle;
alien.X = box.center.X - box.Width / 2;
alien.Y = box.center.Y - box.Height / 2;
alien.angle=angle;
```

but it wasn't translating it correctly.

Had someone ever tried to get corners on this kind of structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In EmguCV you just need to call

```
PointF[] corners = box.GetVertices();
```

if `box` is a `MCvBox2D`.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to get the vertices of a CvBox2D is to convert it to a RotatedRect:

```
CvBox2D box = ...
cv::RotatedRect rr(box);
cv::Point2f vertices[4];
rr.points(vertices);
// vertices now has the four corners your seek
```